# Is it possible to nest a parallel statement in a parallel statement in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, tdengine

Is it possible to nest a parallel statement in a parallel statement in Jenkins?
Something like:
parallel { stage { parallel {} } stage { parallel {} } }
Thanks.``

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Jan 2023) it is not officially supported by Jenkins as described in the documentation here
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel

> It is not possible to nest a parallel or matrix block within a stage directive if that stage directive is nested within a parallel or matrix block itself

However it is possible to do it using a combination of Scripted and Declarative Syntax. Described in this answer
[How to achive nested parallel in Jenkins declarative pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72986221/how-to-achive-nested-parallel-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline)

The only problem with this approach is that such solution is not supported by the Blue Ocean plugin and while the steps will run correctly the visualisation graph will not draw them correctly nested